# How to write a sql statement for concating 2 fields in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Sample:

```
ID firstname lastname
1  jerry     cai
```

I get a String "jerrycai", I need to select from these 2 fields once and combine them then compare with the "jerrycai".

Just a guess that the following might work:

```
 select * from user where firstname+lastname='jerrycai'
```

Is there a method of implementing this in SQL? DB: Access

Comment: Yes, you have the right idea. What to use for concatenation depends on your RDBMS. SQL Server uses `+`, Oracle `||`, MySQL `CONCAT(a, b)`

Comment: Give it a try with the appropriate concatenation operator - it will work as you have guessed.

Comment: Use & for concatenation in MsAccess.

Answer (score 1):

Why concatenate when you can do this:

```
select * 
  from user 
 where firstname = 'jerry'
       AND lastname = 'cai';
```

---

But if you must:

```
select * 
  from user 
 where firstname & lastname = 'jerrycai';
```

Comment: The OP says he get's passed a string `'jerrycai'` so to it this way would require splitting it in the correct place, which'll never work. It does raise the question why the OP isn't being passed 2 strings though...

Comment: @JerryCai: It depends what you mean by 'right'. In Standard SQL, `NULL +  'Cai'` evaluates to UNKNOWN (for which `NULL` is a synonym). In Access SQL, `NULL +  'Cai'` evaluates to `NULL`, so arguably `+` is 'right'.